# Antd Multiple File Upload

Tags: reactjs, upload, antd

[I have created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-manually-antd-5-7-0-forked-cc55qq?file=/demo.js) where I have utilized `Upload manually` component from `Antd` website. It says that this takes `multiple` as a `prop`. I am using `Upload manually` component inside `Dragger`. Even though I can select multiple files when the dialog box shows up by holding `Ctrl`. However, when I finally try to `Open` the files after selecting them it only shows one file name and not multiple file names.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To me it's working fine in codesandbox you provided. Perhaps it's something else in your app.